# ios-sim command and Xcode 6.0 -Not able to start ios8 devices

Tags: ios, cordova, ios-simulator, xcode6

I am using ios-sim utility to start the simulator.We upgraded from xcode 5.1.1 to xcode 6.0 GM.

The application we have is build on SDK 8.0.So when compiling with xcode 6.0 and running on iOS 8.0 simulator works fine.

However when running through ios-sim utility it always trigger on iOS 7 devices.The command is

ios-sim launch pathToMyApp --sdk 8.0 --devicetypeid com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-5s

I changed the command line tools to point to xcode 6.0

What else do I need to check or configure.

Answer (score 0):

ios-sim was designed by reverse engineering the older iOS Simulator.  With Xcode 6, the iOS Simulator is now based on CoreSimualtor.framework.  You should probably transition to using 'xcrun simctl ...' rather than the ios-sim utility.

Answer (score 0):

`ios-sim` has been updated to work with Xcode 6 and iOS Simulator 8.0. Check out the project on GitHub for more details: https://github.com/phonegap/ios-sim